# Calling getter of process returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing

I am currently working on making my program use multiprocessing.Process and I want to get an object from my Process subclass.

Inside **main**.py:

```
p = DataProcessor()
p.start()
#later:
obj = p.x
```

Inside **data_processor**.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
class DataProcessor(Process):
     def __init__(self):
         #call to super etc
         self.x = None

     def run(self):
         while True:
             if self.x is None:
                 self.x = 5 #normally i set this to an object
```

When I now want to use x in my **main** it is always None.
How can I get this to work without having to use a multiprocessing.Queue?
(In my opinion queues are neither readable nor useful when dealing with only one object once)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing Pipe ;)
But seriously, you have to use inter-process communication to share data between the processes. Here is a simple example that retrieves `x` from the child process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time


class DataProcessor(Process):
     def __init__(self, queue):
         #call to super etc
         Process.__init__(self)
         self.queue = queue
         self.x = None

     def run(self):
         while True:
             if self.x is None:
                 self.x = 5 #normally i set this to an object
                 self.queue.put(self.x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    p = DataProcessor(queue)
    p.start()
    #later:
    while queue.empty():
        time.sleep(.1)
    x = queue.get()
    print(x)
```

Comment: is the `while` loop in the **main** even necessary? i thought queue.get would do something similar.

Comment: You're correct. I've been working more with pipes recently.